# jQuery. Need assistance with .hover events

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="one" class="hover">Hover there</div>
<div id="one-child" class="box"><div class="region"></div></div>

jQuery(function($) {
$(".hover").hover(function() {
    var targetId = "#" + this.id + "-child"; //Get the id of the new active box
    $(".box").not(targetId).stop(true, true).hide(); //Stop any previous animations and hide the boxes, if they are not the same as the active box.
    $(targetId).fadeIn(); //Show the current, active box
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
}, $.noop); //Provide jQuery's empty function so nothing gets done on mouseleave.
});


jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!jQuery(event.target).hasClass("box")) { //If the source of the click is a .box, don't do anything.
        jQuery(".box").fadeOut(); //Otherwise fadeOut() the box
        jQuery(".active").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

**EDITED 3**

http://kazpost.webcoder.kz → all works as intended.
But only one problem left :)) i've placed another div inside #one-child. When i press on that div.region inside #one-child → div.box is closes.

Comment: replace `this.attr` with `$(this).attr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT, for latest question:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    if (jQuery(event.target).closest(".box").length == 0) {
        jQuery(".box").fadeOut();
        jQuery(".act").removeClass("act");
    }
});
```

Handling the click can be done using the closest() function to determine whether or not the clicked element is inside a `.box`.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot. But now only 1 thing left. For example if im gonna create #box2 with another content, and #hover2. How can i check if all previous #box(es) closed? look at here http://kazpost.webcoder.kz

Comment: You can use an attribute selector `jQuery("[id^='box']")` which will retrieve any element whose id starts with "box".

Comment: Are you trying to get a box to popup on mouseover from each blue box and hide either when you mouseover another blue box or click somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the code. But can u update it a bit. When you hover over div id="one" it gets class .active, and then when u click somewhere on the page except one-child class .active disappears. Second thing is when you click on child-one div it disappears, it is possible to make when i click on child-one it wouldn't disappear. It would dissapear only if i click on every element of the page except child-one div.

Comment: Here's exactly what i needed. http://www.royalmail.com/portal/rm
but i fail at writing my own code to dublicate this functionality...

Comment: Here is the update: http://jsfiddle.net/EajfY/2/ I was using srcElement instead of target, so it worked in Chrome, but not FF.  I also remove .active when you hover over another .hover element

Comment: Thanks, what if i want to use another ID's?

Comment: Thanks, mate! You are jQuery master! Love you :D

Comment: Ooops... it still closes when i click on div.region.. look it here please http://kazpost.webcoder.kz. It now not closing div.box when i click outside that div.

Comment: I put `x != 0`.  It should either be `x==0` or `x!= 1`.  What you are checking basically is that the element you clicked on is not a child of a `.box`, which means `closest()` should have zero elements.

Comment: Thanks, but where i should place it?

Comment: I edited the original post to be correct.  Just remove the exclamation point/negation operator from the jQuery(...).closest() line

Comment: Thank you very much, mate! How can you learn jQuery so good? Can you point me to some books to read about jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(this.attr('id') == 'box') return;
```

to

```
if($(this).attr('id') == 'box') return;
```

and

```
this.fadeOut('slow');
```

to

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: thanks, now this error has been gone. At this moment when i click on any element on the page it makes fade effect :D Seems like problem is in $(this) it selects wrong element in DOM